# Is it possible to establish a precedence of cucumber scenarios?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I have to test a web page which generate a lot of information.

It's only a feature but it has several panels and content that must be tested.

I was planning to divide it into several scenarios, each one testing a separate part of the page.

Nevertheless, there are 4 scenarios that must be passing so I can test the rest of the scenarios (they will fail if any of the other 4 fail).

I was wondering if it's possible to establish a dependency or precedence between scenarios of a same feature. I want cucumber to stop running the rest of the scenarios if one of the first 4 fails.

Comment: Why not put the scenarios in 1 file?

Answer (score 1):

I have not found a way to decide which tests to run first.
We have a script to run the tests, then you can says that you have a set of
tests tagged with for example @smoke
If the running of these tests fails, then we will not run the next command in the script.

When running from for example Jenkins you can make the job run two scripts, the first to run only the @Smoke-tagged tests. If these fails, then the CI-server will not continue to run the second set of tests